# Ubuntu Upgrade 14.04 -> 16.04 LTS / Failure

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel

Good afternoon.  Yesterday I received notice on my box, that an upgrade was available (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).  Having done upgrades before, I selected **'yes'** to continue with the upgrade.  Things went fine until an error msg came up saying a few *sources* could not be found, but to reboot.  After rebooting, yup - ***kernel panic*** and no Ubuntu at all.

I tried several ***rescue disks*** and nothing worked.  So I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Live CD and saw an option to *reinstall* the previous upgrade.  Unfortunately as fate would have it, there was no ***upgrade*** and it wiped my system clean.  Not that I wouldn't of preferred this, but I assumed that the upgrade would just upgrade the OS and not wipe everything.

So, knowing that nothing is really ***deleted*** is there an easy way to recover the files?  Any good recommendations on live CD's I could try?